# URL rewriting using Codeigniter for specific rule

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

On my local server, I have setup a website using Codeigniter which opens up fine using below URL

I have a different kind of query regarding rewriting URL

```
http://localhost/mywebsite
```

Actually the real URL is  below

```
http://localhost/mywebsite/page/
```

Which I want it to work as root url as

```
http://localhost/mywebsite
```

So I have done it by adding it as default controller in config.php

But now I have another URL as

```
http://localhost/mywebsite/page/mypagename
```

Which should open as

```
http://localhost/mywebsite/mypagename
```

How can I do it?

Comment: why don't you just map it in the routes?

Answer (score 0):

You can define a custom route in /system/application/config/routes.php - for example:

```
$route['abc'] = 'controller_name/abc';

Then, http://mydemosite.com/abc
goes to http://mydemosite.com/controller_name/abc
```

see https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/routing.html for more information of URI Routing.

I hope this can be helping you.

Comment: Actually mypagename is going to be dynamic so it should be anything, so I can not route it like this. May be some kind of regular expression in routing may help?

Answer (score 0):

I got it solved using routing method as below under config/routes.php

```
$route['([^/]+)/?'] = 'page/$1';
```